# Add a prefix to all Flask routes

Tags: python, routes, flask

I have a prefix that I want to add to every route.  Right now I add a constant to the route at every definition.  Is there a way to do this automatically?

```
PREFIX = "/abc/123"

@app.route(PREFIX + "/")
def index_page():
  return "This is a website about burritos"

@app.route(PREFIX + "/about")
def about_page():
  return "This is a website about burritos"
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The answer depends on how you are serving this application.

### Sub-mounted inside of another WSGI container

Assuming that you are going to run this application inside of a WSGI container (mod_wsgi, uwsgi, gunicorn, etc); you need to actually *mount, at that prefix* the application as a sub-part of that WSGI container (anything that speaks WSGI will do) and to set your [`APPLICATION_ROOT`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#builtin-configuration-values) config value to your prefix:

```
app.config["APPLICATION_ROOT"] = "/abc/123"

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "The URL for this page is {}".format(url_for("index"))

# Will return "The URL for this page is /abc/123/"
```

Setting the [`APPLICATION_ROOT`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#builtin-configuration-values) config value simply limit Flask's session cookie to that URL prefix.  Everything else will be automatically handled for you by Flask and Werkzeug's excellent WSGI handling capabilities.

#### An example of properly sub-mounting your app

If you are not sure what the first paragraph means, take a look at this example application with Flask mounted inside of it:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
 
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/abc/123'
 
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'The URL for this page is {}'.format(url_for('index'))

def simple(env, resp):
    resp(b'200 OK', [(b'Content-Type', b'text/plain')])
    return [b'Hello WSGI World']

app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(simple, {'/abc/123': app.wsgi_app})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('localhost', 5000)
```

### Proxying requests to the app

If, on the other hand, you will be running your Flask application at the root of its WSGI container and proxying requests to it (for example, if it's being FastCGI'd to, or if nginx is `proxy_pass`-ing requests for a sub-endpoint to your stand-alone `uwsgi` / `gevent` server then you can either:

- Use a Blueprint, as Miguel points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969161/135978).
- *or* use the `DispatcherMiddleware` from `werkzeug` (or the `PrefixMiddleware` from [su27's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033627/135978)) to sub-mount your application in the stand-alone WSGI server you're using.  (See *An example of properly sub-mounting your app* above for the code to use).

Comment: @jknupp - looking at [`flask.Flask#create_url_adapter`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/807067001f58272429fd67396ba2c2c5b2e85861/flask/app.py#L1670-1690) and [`werkzeug.routing.Map#bind_to_environ`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/8f311d277d00ed61a10d054cdd763384ad7a1012/werkzeug/routing.py#L1219-1222) it looks like it *should* work - how were you running the code?  (The app actually needs to be mounted on the sub-path in a WSGI environment for `url_for` to return the expected value.)

Comment: I ran exactly what you wrote, but added

    app = Flask(__name__)

and

    app.run(debug=True)

Comment: @jknupp - that is the problem - you'll need to actually mount the application as a sub-part of a larger application (anything that speaks WSGI will do).  I've whipped up [an example gist](https://gist.github.com/svieira/3434cbcaf627e50a4808) and updated my answer to make it clearer that I'm assuming a sub-mounted WSGI environment, not a stand-alone WSGI environment behind a proxy which is only forwarding sub-path requests.

Comment: This works, using the `DispatcherMiddleware` approach, when running flask by itself. Can't quite seem to get this working when running behind Gunicorn.

Comment: @Justin - are you running `parent_app` or just `app` via your Gunicorn configuration?  (You need to target `parent_app` as your WSGI application).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks @SeanVieira. I have a subclass of Flask (for some other customizations) so I'll probably need to override `wsgi_app`, or I could just override `add_url_rule`, maybe this is easier?

Comment: I believe there is a typo in the sub-mounting example. Replacing "simple" with "run_simple" in the app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware() call works for me.

Comment: The way mount to sub path in uwsgi `uwsgi -s /tmp/yourapplication.sock --manage-script-name --mount /yourapplication=myapp:app` . detail refer to (uwsgi document)[http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/uwsgi/]

Comment: When I add APPLICATION_ROOT I get `...
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/vocprez/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 165, in handle_request
    resp, environ = wsgi.create(req, client, addr,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/vocprez/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/http/wsgi.py", line 183, in create
    path_info = path_info.split(script_name, 1)[1]
IndexError: list index out of range`
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: SOLVED: make sure your proxy_pass directive contains the subdirectory. 
 See: https://dlukes.github.io/flask-wsgi-url-prefix.html for more details

Comment: @ChrisCummings 's comment might have been missed.  I needed to change this bit of code: `DispatcherMiddleware(simple, {'/abc/123': app.wsgi_app})` to this `DispatcherMiddleware(run_simple, {'/abc/123': app.wsgi_app})` to fix the typo. Thank you @sean-viera for posting this solution. 

Answer (score 147):

You can put your routes in a blueprint:

```
bp = Blueprint('burritos', __name__,
                        template_folder='templates')

@bp.route("/")
def index_page():
  return "This is a website about burritos"

@bp.route("/about")
def about_page():
  return "This is a website about burritos"
```

Then you register the blueprint with the application using a prefix:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix='/abc/123')
```

Comment: Hi Miguel; do you know the difference between registering a url_prefix for a blueprint as you did below with `app.register_blueprint` and between registering it when you instantiate the Blueprint object above, by passing `url_prefix='/abc/123`? Thank you!

Comment: The difference is that having the URL prefix in the `register_blueprint` call gives the application the freedom to "mount" the blueprint anywhere it wants, or even mount the same blueprint multiple times on different URLs. If you put the prefix in the blueprint itself you make it easier for the application, but you have less flexibility.

Comment: Thank you!! That is very helpful. I was confused by the apparent redundancy but I see the trade-off between the two options.

Comment: And actually, I never tried this, but it is likely that you can combine URL prefixes both in the blueprint and the app, with the app's prefix fist, followed by the blueprint prefix.

Comment: Note that it is necessary to register the blueprint *after* the blueprint.route decorated functions.

Comment: @Miguel What I have to do if I further wants to prefix an url which was already registered as Blueprint? Ie. I just want to add `/api` after `123` and I don't want to attach `api` after `123` in the url_prefix

Comment: I'm a little confused on where each "part" of this code should go? I have an "app" folder with an __init__.py that contians my app.run code. I have an __init__.py file one directory above that that sets my logger and the has the Flask(__name__) line. I then have a separate routes.py file with all my routes. Where do I put each line of this sample code to try this method out?

Comment: The location doesn't really matter, Flask does not care. You can write the blueprint in a separate module inside your app package if you want to keep things organized.

Comment: This does not work for static files though, how to go about it?

Comment: You can define your own static route inside the blueprint. Use the `send_from_directory()` function to implement the route.

Comment: Your redirects in view functions (or classes) will also require adjusting such that the blueprint name is included in it. For example, instead of 

return redirect(url_for('index_page'))
you will need to have this:
return redirect(url_for('burritos.index_page'))

Comment: Don't forget to additionally set the `app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/abc/123'` Otherwise your cookies won't work and thus no login, logout, etc

Answer (score 76):

You should note that the `APPLICATION_ROOT` is NOT for this purpose.

All you have to do is to write a middleware to make the following changes:

1. modify `PATH_INFO` to handle the prefixed url.
2. modify `SCRIPT_NAME` to generate the prefixed url.

Like this:

```
class PrefixMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, app, prefix=''):
        self.app = app
        self.prefix = prefix

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):

        if environ['PATH_INFO'].startswith(self.prefix):
            environ['PATH_INFO'] = environ['PATH_INFO'][len(self.prefix):]
            environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = self.prefix
            return self.app(environ, start_response)
        else:
            start_response('404', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
            return ["This url does not belong to the app.".encode()]
```

Wrap your app with the middleware, like this:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.wsgi_app = PrefixMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, prefix='/foo')


@app.route('/bar')
def bar():
    return "The URL for this page is {}".format(url_for('bar'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 9010)
```

Visit `http://localhost:9010/foo/bar`,

You will get the right result: `The URL for this page is /foo/bar`

And don't forget to set the cookie domain if you need to.

This solution is given by [Larivact's gist](https://gist.github.com/Larivact/1ee3bad0e53b2e2c4e40). The `APPLICATION_ROOT` is not for this job, although it looks like to be. It's really confusing.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer. Tried the other solutions posted here, but this is the only one that worked for me. A+++I'm deployed on IIS using wfastcgi.py

Comment: "The `APPLICATION_ROOT` is not for this job" - this is where I was going wrong. I wish `Blueprint`'s `url_prefix` parameter and `APPLICATION_ROOT` were combined by default, so that I could have `APPLICATION_ROOT` scope urls for the entire app, and `url_prefix` scope urls within `APPLICATION_ROOT` just for the individual blueprint. Sigh

Comment: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/monkpit/68e019ac5c64f943f51708b638da9da4) for an example of what I was trying to do using `APPLICATION_ROOT`.

Comment: If you're using gunicorn, SCRIPT_NAME is already supported. Set it as an environment variable or pass it through as an http header: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/faq.html

Comment: Can you confirm your code? `TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
` Looks like the class takes an object?

Comment: The code as it stands did not work for me. After some research, I came up with this after the else in the `__call__` method: `response = Response('That url is not correct for this application', status=404)
            return response(environ, start_response)` using `from werkzeug.wrappers import BaseResponse as Response`

Comment: alll you have to ... is try the proposed solution to find out it does not work ...

Comment: This solution works "from the outside", when the user requests a page from the server. However, if I call `flask.redirect('/')`, it will go to the real `/` without applying the prefix.

Answer (score 13):

This is more of a python answer than a Flask/werkzeug answer; but it's simple and works.

If, like me, you want your application settings (loaded from an `.ini` file) to also contain the prefix of your Flask application (thus, not to have the value set during deployment, but during runtime), you can opt for the following:

```
def prefix_route(route_function, prefix='', mask='{0}{1}'):
  '''
    Defines a new route function with a prefix.
    The mask argument is a `format string` formatted with, in that order:
      prefix, route
  '''
  def newroute(route, *args, **kwargs):
    '''New function to prefix the route'''
    return route_function(mask.format(prefix, route), *args, **kwargs)
  return newroute
```

Arguably, this is somewhat hackish and relies on the fact that the Flask route function *requires* a `route` as a first positional argument.

You can use it like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.route = prefix_route(app.route, '/your_prefix')
```

*NB: It is worth nothing that it is possible to use a variable in the prefix (for example by setting it to `/<prefix>`), and then process this prefix in the functions you decorate with your `@app.route(...)`. If you do so, you obviously have to declare the `prefix` parameter in your decorated function(s). In addition, you might want to check the submitted prefix against some rules, and return a 404 if the check fails. In order to avoid a 404 custom re-implementation, please `from werkzeug.exceptions import NotFound` and then `raise NotFound()` if the check fails.*

Comment: It's simple and more efficient than using `Blueprint`. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 5):

So, I believe that a valid answer to this is: the prefix should be configured in the actual server application that you use when development is completed. Apache, nginx, etc.

However, if you would like this to work during development while running the Flask app in debug, take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rduplain/1705072).

### Flask's `DispatcherMiddleware` to the rescue!

I'll copy the code here for posterity:

```
"Serve a Flask app on a sub-url during localhost development."

from flask import Flask


APPLICATION_ROOT = '/spam'


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)  # I think this adds APPLICATION_ROOT
                                  # to the config - I'm not exactly sure how!
# alternatively:
# app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = APPLICATION_ROOT


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Relevant documents:
    # http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/middlewares/
    # http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    # Load a dummy app at the root URL to give 404 errors.
    # Serve app at APPLICATION_ROOT for localhost development.
    application = DispatcherMiddleware(Flask('dummy_app'), {
        app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT']: app,
    })
    run_simple('localhost', 5000, application, use_reloader=True)
```

Now, when running the above code as a standalone Flask app, `http://localhost:5000/spam/` will display `Hello, world!`.

In a comment on another answer, I expressed that I wished to do something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

# Let's pretend module_blueprint defines a route, '/record/<id>/'
from some_submodule.flask import module_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/api'
app.register_blueprint(module_blueprint, url_prefix='/some_submodule')
app.run()

# I now would like to be able to get to my route via this url:
# http://host:8080/api/some_submodule/record/1/
```

Applying `DispatcherMiddleware` to my contrived example:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask.serving import run_simple
from flask.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

# Let's pretend module_blueprint defines a route, '/record/<id>/'
from some_submodule.flask import module_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/api'
app.register_blueprint(module_blueprint, url_prefix='/some_submodule')
application = DispatcherMiddleware(Flask('dummy_app'), {
    app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT']: app
})
run_simple('localhost', 5000, application, use_reloader=True)

# Now, this url works!
# http://host:8080/api/some_submodule/record/1/
```

Comment: "So, I believe that a valid answer to this is: the prefix should be configured in the actual server application that you use when development is completed. Apache, nginx, etc." The problem is in redirects; if you have a prefix and don't set it up in Flask, then when it redirects instead of going to /yourprefix/path/to/url it just goes to /path/to/url. Is there a way to set up, in nginx or Apache, what the prefix has to be?

Comment: The way I would probably do this is just to use a configuration management tool like puppet or chef, and set the prefix there and then have the tool propagate the change to the config files where it needs to go. I'm not going to even pretend that I know what I'm talking about for apache or nginx. Since this question/answer was specific to python, I would encourage you to post your scenario as a separate question. If you do this, feel free to link to the question here!

Answer (score 3):

Another completely different way is with **mountpoints** in `uwsgi`.

*From the doc about [Hosting multiple apps in the same process](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html#hosting-multiple-apps-in-the-same-process-aka-managing-script-name-and-path-info) ([permalink](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docs/blob/0818827ad0606aac46fec873b545a7c845458c6d/Nginx.rst#hosting-multiple-apps-in-the-same-process-aka-managing-script_name-and-path_info)).*

In your `uwsgi.ini` you add

```
[uwsgi]
mount = /foo=main.py
manage-script-name = true

# also stuff which is not relevant for this, but included for completeness sake:    
module = main
callable = app
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
```

If you don't call your file `main.py`, you need to change both the `mount` and the `module`

Your `main.py` could look like this:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/bar')
def bar():
  return "The URL for this page is {}".format(url_for('bar'))
# end def
```

And a nginx config (again for completeness):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com

  location /foo {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///temp/uwsgi.sock;
  }
}
```

Now calling `example.com/foo/bar` will display `/foo/bar` as returned by flask's `url_for('bar')`, as it adapts automatically. That way your links will work without prefix problems.

Answer (score 3):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix='/abc/123')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug='True', port=4444)


bp = Blueprint('burritos', __name__,
                        template_folder='templates')

@bp.route('/')
def test():
    return "success"
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation.

Comment: Two nice explanations I found were in [exploreflask](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html) and the [official docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/)

Answer (score 1):

I needed similar so called "context-root". I did it in conf file under /etc/httpd/conf.d/ using WSGIScriptAlias :

### myapp.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /home/<myid>/myapp/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/<myid>/myapp>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

So now I can access my app as : http://localhost:5000/myapp

See the guide - http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

My solution where flask and PHP apps coexist
nginx and PHP5.6

KEEP Flask in root and PHP in subdirectories

```sh
sudo vi /etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini
```

Add 1 line

```sh
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

```sh
sudo vi /etc/php/5.6/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
listen = /run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock

uwsgi

sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

USE NESTED LOCATIONS for PHP and let FLASK remain in root

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    # Serve a static file (ex. favico) outside static dir.
    location = /favico.ico  {    
        root /var/www/html/favico.ico;    
    }

    # Proxying connections to application servers
    location / {
        include            uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass         127.0.0.1:5000;
    }

    location /pcdp {
        location ~* \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        location ~* \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

READ carefully
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms

We need to understand location matching
(none): If no modifiers are present, the location is interpreted as a prefix match. This means that the location given will be matched against the beginning of the request URI to determine a match.
=: If an equal sign is used, this block will be considered a match if the request URI exactly matches the location given.
~: If a tilde modifier is present, this location will be interpreted as a case-sensitive regular expression match.
~*: If a tilde and asterisk modifier is used, the location block will be interpreted as a case-insensitive regular expression match.
^~: If a carat and tilde modifier is present, and if this block is selected as the best non-regular expression match, regular expression matching will not take place.

Order is important, from nginx's "location" description:

To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among them, the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and remembered. Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is used. If no match with a regular expression is found then the configuration of the prefix location remembered earlier is used.

It means:

```
First =. ("longest matching prefix" match)
Then implicit ones. ("longest matching prefix" match)
Then regex. (first match)
```

Answer (score 1):

For people still struggling with this, the first example does work, but the full example is here if you have a Flask app that is not under your control:

```
from os import getenv
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from custom_app import app

application = DispatcherMiddleware(
    app, {getenv("REBROW_BASEURL", "/rebrow"): app}
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_simple(
        "0.0.0.0",
        int(getenv("REBROW_PORT", "5001")),
        application,
        use_debugger=False,
        threaded=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

In **flask blueprint**, we can use -

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/prefix-text'
```

Anyone looking to do in **flask-restful** can make use of -

[doc link](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#id1)

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app, prefix='/pefix-text')
```

Now, all your routes will be prefixed with `/prefix-text`. Just make sure you use `url_for('link')` in places where you might have simply used a `/link`.

Answer (score 1):

From all the answers I have seen above, they are either too simplistic or over complicating.

That said, I like to accomplish it using *nested blueprints*:

```py
from .blueprints import blueprint1, blueprint2, blueprint3, etc


app = Flask(__name__)

url_prefix = "/abc/123"
parent = Blueprint('index', __name__, url_prefix=url_prefix)

index.register_blueprint(blueprint1)
index.register_blueprint(blueprint2)
index.register_blueprint(blueprint3)
app.register_blueprint(index)
```

This way, you basically link your child blueprints to a parent blueprint, where you define the prefix. This is documented [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/).

With your example, you would simply rewrite it to:

```py
blueprint1 = Blueprint('blueprint1', __name__)

@blueprint1.route("/")
def index_page():
  return "Index page"

@blueprint1.route("/about")
def about_page():
  return "About page"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle the prefix when using Nginx as a reverse proxy. Werkzeug's `ProxyFix` middleware will be a simpler solution:

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(
    app.wsgi_app, x_for=1, x_proto=1, x_host=1, x_prefix=1
)
```

Werkzeug will read the `X-Forwarded-Prefix` header and set it to `SCRIPT_NAME`. So be sure to set the `X-Forwarded-Prefix` header in Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /api;
    }
}
```

See more details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75123044/5511849

Answer (score 0):

I think su27's answer is right. And I am using gevent, here is my code and it works fine:

```py
from gevent import pywsgi

# your flask code ...
# app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class MyHandler(pywsgi.WSGIHandler):
        def get_environ(self):
            prefix = "/your_prefix"
            env = super().get_environ()
            if env['PATH_INFO'].startswith(prefix):
                env['PATH_INFO'] = env['PATH_INFO'][len(prefix):]
                env['SCRIPT_NAME'] = prefix
            return env
    
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 8080), app, handler_class=MyHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to add the prefix in some way,

take a look at the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73883005/553095
and https://github.com/mskimm/prefixed-superset

Answer (score 0):

I am using `ApiFlask` application via both embedded dev server (dev env) and `gunicorn` (staging and production env). I believe the solution will work for vanilla `Flask` as well.

I wanted to have the configuration at one place - package `__init__.py` file, that imports route definitions placed within `views.py` file, not to have it scampered across more files or some part before route definition and the rest after them. Solution via `Blueprint` makes me annotate routes specifically, which I understand but feel that it is a bit overkill for my case.

The solution is based on `DispatcherMiddleware` and everything necessary is placed to the package root file (`__init__.py`). I am taking the prefix from an environment variable, but that doesn't matter.

Note that automatically generated OAS documentation **is also accessible** under a prefixed route.

Minimal example follows:

```
from apiflask import APIFlask
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware
import os

route_prefix = os.getenv('APP_ROUTE_PREFIX', '')

def create_app():
    app = APIFlask(
            __name__,
            title="OAS3 Application title",
            version="0.2",
            docs_path='/docs',
            spec_path='/openapi.json'
    )
    app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = route_prefix

    return app

app = create_app()
app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(app, {route_prefix: app.wsgi_app})

from app.views import *
```