# Add route prefix to Flask application running behing Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

**tldr;** Looking for a way to prefix all routes within an app running behind Gunicorn without a reverse proxy/blueprint/duplicate prefix in `@route(PREFIX + '/')` etc.

---

Creating a few Python services, using Flask, running in Docker containers.
Not, currently, using Nginx/Apache for reverse proxying.

Have something like below that works when running flask by itself
 - *(eg `% python app.py` responds with `localhost:5000/a/b/some-route`)*

```
base_path = "/a/b"
app = DispatcherMiddleware(_root_app, {base_path: self})
run_simple(host, port, app, **options)
```

Not sure how to achieve the same result when running behind Gunicorn.
*(Would really like to do this without making a blueprint for the main app. Also trying to avoid having the same prefix in every `@route(PREFIX + '')`)*

**Reason for doing this**
Using an extension that adds a few routes, along with a blueprint. Would like to have app routes AND extension/blueprint routes to all be prefixed.

> [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441/add-a-prefix-to-all-flask-routes) asked this specifically for Flask, which I'm able to get working using the `DispatcherMiddleware` approach.
>   My question is how to get this working when running behind Gunicorn (no Nginx or Apache in front, just Gunicorn)

---

### Potential Fix:

Currently using a subclass of Flask *(needed to do some customized logging nonsense.)*
Overriding the `add_url_rule` works.

```
prefixed_rule = self._prefix_rule(rule)
super().add_url_rule(prefixed_rule,
                     endpoint=endpoint,
                     view_func=view_func,
                     **options)
```

*This also works with our extensions too*

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing that requires multiple non-compossible services to be treated as one site?  Is this for app dependency isolation?  And why not have a reverse-proxy in front of them all?

Comment: It's just for some micro-services, so there will be a single endpoint. Just have some extensions that need to be prefixed as well as the app. We currently have a reverse proxy in place, but this may change going forward so we wanted to do this at the route level if/when it does change on us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are doing app composition, then you can use the [`DispatcherMiddleware` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441/add-a-prefix-to-all-flask-routes) you referenced.  However, it sounds like you are trying to have a single service that is subpath mounted, but doesn't serve anything out of the "higher" paths at all.

There are several different ways to do this.

1. Replace [`Flask.url_map._rules`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.url_map) with a [`werkzeug.routing.Submount`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Submount) rule factory:

   ```
   from werkzeug.routing import SubPath

   app = Flask(__name__)

   # register blueprints and extensions
   # load config, etc.

   app.url_map._rules = SubPath(app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'], app.url_map._rules)
   ```
2. Replace [`Flask.url_rule_class`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.url_rule_class):

   ```
   from werkzeug.routing import Rule

   app.url_rule_class = lambda path, **options: Rule(PREFIX + path, **options)
   ```
3. Replace `add_url_rule`, as you suggest in your question.

Comment: I originally had #3 implemented, quick/easy, but I do like #2 a bit more so I've gone with something similar (using a closure, in-place of the lambda. That dang PEP8 =)

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix all routes for a specific blueprint

```
from flask import Blueprint
my_blueprint = Blueprint('my_blueprint_name', __name__, url_prefix='/my_prefix')
```

then for all your routes for the blue print simply put

```
@my_blueprint.route('my_route')
```

before the function definition and its route will be the url_prefix+my_route

You may find this link helpful http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/urlprocessors/

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing this in a blueprint, as this wouldn't prefix other extensions being used in the app.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    server=server,
    routes_pathname_prefix='/dash/'
)
```