# Define URL root with flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have multiple routes which have the same URL root.
Example:

- abc/def/upload
- abc/def/list
- abc/def/page/{page_id}

Can I define **abc/def** to be URL root. (Something similar to what can be done in Java using Spring or Apache CXF)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In *flask-restful* it is possible to prefix all your routes on [api initialization](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#id1):

```
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>> api = restful.Api(app, prefix='/abc/def')
```

You can then wire your resources ignoring any prefixes:

```
>>> api.add_resource(MyResource, '/upload')
>>> ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `APPLICATION_ROOT` key for your app's config.

```
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = "/abc/def"
```

source - [Add a prefix to all Flask routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441/add-a-prefix-to-all-flask-routes)

Comment: the one with blueprint works without any hassles. The above solution requires context of WSGI application.

Comment: You should probably add an answer which works better for posterity.

Comment: @Harshdeep So why not to use the blueprint?

Answer (score 0):

I needed similar so called "context-root". I did it in conf file under /etc/httpd/conf.d/ using WSGIScriptAlias :

### myapp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /home/<myid>/myapp/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/<myid>/myapp>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

So now I can access my app as : http://localhost:5000/myapp

See the guide - http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Blueprint` from `Flask`:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
bp = Blueprint('', __name__, url_prefix="/abc/def")

def upload():
    pass

def list():
    pass

bp.add_url_rule('/upload', 'upload', view_func=upload)
bp.add_url_rule('/list', 'list', view_func=list)
...

app.register_blueprint(bp)
```