# Proper URL routing configuration for Flask with proxy pass

Tags: flask

I'm struggling to find the proper way to setup my flask routes when moving my app to being hosted in a subdirectory.  I've read a bunch of great answers on this subject, most notably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441/add-a-prefix-to-all-flask-routes#18967744) on adding a prefix to all routes.  However, I think my situation is slightly different.  I want to ONLY prefix the URLs I generate with `url_for`, not respond to those URLs.  Is there a way to do this?

For example, assume my flask app is hosted at `http://www.acme.com/tools/`. The main `acme.com` domain is setup with a proxy pass to pass all requests from `/tools/*` to my app.  So, my app only sees requests like `/`, `/product_1/` even though the full URL is `http://www.acme.com/tools/product_`/, etc.  So, my `app.route` rules can use `/` as the base route.  The problem is I use `url_for` everywhere and I want the urls generated to be the full url like `/tools/product_1`, **not** `/product_1`.  Is there a way to achieve this?

I've tried using blueprints but those will make the `@app.route` and `url_for` respond to `/tools/xyz`.  Is there a more simple solution to this issue or is this a non-standard way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at this snippet: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/

I'm not sure I love the idea of modifying your WSGI environment as the only solution to this problem. You can always wrap url_for. (note that this won't work for `_external=True`)

```
def my_url_for(*args, **kwargs):
    return '/tools' + url_for(*args, **kwargs)
```

Be sure to set your `APPLICATION_ROOT` to `/tools` so that cookies are only accessible from the app.

Comment: I've considered wrapping `url_for` too. The downside though I have to pay careful attention to always use my wrapper instead of the regular function, which is confusing to contributors on the project.  However, this might be the only good option.

Answer (score 1):

I found a different way to handle this without having to provide a wrapper for `url_for`.  I'm using a custom routing rule to append the prefix.  This means none of the `app.route` decorator calls have to be changed and all calls to `url_for` will automatically get the prefix added.  Are there any caveats I'm missing by overriding the `url_rule_class`?

Add the following to your `__init__.py` after setting up your app.

```
from werkzeug.routing import Rule
class PrefixRule(Rule):
    def build(self, *args, **kwargs):
        domain_part, url = super(PrefixRule, self).build(*args, **kwargs)

        return domain_part, u'%s%s' % (app.config['PREFIX'], url)


app.url_rule_class = PrefixRule
```