# How can I serve static files in Flask when the application root changes

Tags: flask

In my `base.html`, I currently have two lines to handle both a local (debugging) serving and the remote (production) serving. This is to make sure that one of locations are served. For instance:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/otherroot/static/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

This is of course silly and I am looking for a better solution so I do not get a 404 each time.

I was hoping `app.config["APPLICATION_ROOT"]` could help as in [Add a prefix to all Flask routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441/add-a-prefix-to-all-flask-routes) and in the two `app.py` files with `create_app` and `app.run()` I have set the `app.config["APPLICATION_ROOT"]` to either '/' and '/otherroot/'.

I have also tried `send_from_directory` from [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask) but that neither seems to work.

**Update**

The first part of `base.html` reads

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block head %}
{{super()}}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/otherroot/static/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
...
```

Note that the application is also using `StaticCDN` which complicate things.

Comment: Is `base.html` a static file or a template? If a template, could you include the code that's rendering it?

Comment: `base.html` is a template that other templates extends from. I have added the first part of that file.

Comment: Can't you pass `APPLICATION ROOT` as a parameter to the template and modify the links into `href="{{ application_root }}/static/.."`?

Comment: I suppose I could. But that would mean that I have to modify all the views to add this extra parameter with something like: `return render_template('index.html', application_root=current_app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'])`

Comment: I have implemented patterns similar to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.dataTables.min.css') }}">` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351826/link-to-flask-static-files-with-url-for and it seems to work on both servers.