# Setting up Apache Superset with Nginx as Reverse Proxy

Tags: python, nginx, centos, reverse-proxy, apache-superset

I'm having trouble setting up apache superset with Nginx as a reverse proxy (This is probably an nginx misconfig).

Server block of config (if I'm missing something, let me know and I'll add it):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/data;
    error_log   /var/www/bokehapps/log/nginx.error.log info;
    location /static {
        alias /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/static;
    }

 
    location /superset {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8088;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_connect_timeout 600;
        proxy_send_timeout 600;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        send_timeout 600;
    }
}
```

I'm able to curl into 0.0.0.0:8088 to get a redirect page, and my request are making it to werkzeug. But in my browser, everything is 404.

Comment: Instead of using `0.0.0.0` try using `127.0.0.1` in both nginx `proxy_pass` and browser

Answer (score 6):

Since you are serving on a prefixed location (`/superset`), and even though you are proxy passing to `/`, werkzeug is trying to serve `/superset` route, which does not exist, hence 404.

What you should to is define a prefix middleware, a very nice explanation can be found in this thread: [Add a prefix to all Flask routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441/add-a-prefix-to-all-flask-routes/36033627#36033627) .

The middleware should than be passed to Superset/FAB as part of the `superset-config.py`, [relevant documentation](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#middleware)

Combining the two you'll likely end up with something like this in your `superset-config.py`:

```
class PrefixMiddleware(object):

def __init__(self, app, prefix='superset'):
    self.app = app
    self.prefix = prefix

def __call__(self, environ, start_response):

    if environ['PATH_INFO'].startswith(self.prefix):
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = environ['PATH_INFO'][len(self.prefix):]
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = self.prefix
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
    else:
        start_response('404', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
        return ["This url does not belong to the app.".encode()]
    
ADDITIONAL_MIDDLEWARE = [PrefixMiddleware, ]
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm trying your solution but am stuck on where to put superset-config.py. Any pointers gratefully appreciated.

Comment: @mappingdom I have it in the same directory where you run the `superset runserver` command, should be picked up

Comment: This is a great solution, but breaks most of the static content as the browser requests them with the `/static` prefix and not `/superset/static`