# flask/werkzeug alias similar to Apache?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, werkzeug

I have a flask app that I test in my dev environment with werkzeug but deploy with Apache and `mod_wsgi`.  In my Apache config I have this classic setting:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /foo /var/www/html/foo.wsgi
```

That's great and now my API's URL is like `www.blah.com/foo/API/0.1`.  However, this makes my dev environment's URL `www.whatever.com/API/0.1` which is weird, lol.

How can I define an "alias" similar to the one I've defined with Apache so that my URLs served by werkzeug take the form of `www.whatever.com/foo/API/0.1`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer but it was *not* easy to find.  So I'm adding this answer here in case anyone's trying the same Google queries I was lol.  This is largely based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969161/224912).

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint("bar", __name__)
```

Now I can conditionally register the blueprint with or without a `url_prefix`.  So if my dev mode flag is set:

```
app.register_blueprint(bp, url_prefix='/foo')
```

Otherwise, in production:

```
app.register_blueprint(bp)
```

Then everywhere I have `@app.route()` replace it with `@bp.route()` :)