# AirBnB knowledge repo: Deploying using a context route

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, knowledge-repo

This post has to do with deploying AirBnBs [knowledge repo](https://github.com/airbnb/knowledge-repo) app.

We are hosting our knowledge-repo on a sub-route of our server - for example `https://aws.our-server-uri.com/knowledge-repo` and I'm running into issues with loading static content and redirects. 
In summary, I have no way of making the knowledge_repo Flask app aware that the app is running on a sub-route.

**The issues**

The first issue I ran into was making gunicorn aware of the context route in order to successfully locate the static files, which are now at `/knowledge-repo/static/...` and not relative to the root url. I solved this by setting the `SCRIPT_NAME` environment variable to `/knowledge-repo` before running `knowledge_repo --repo . deploy`. *I'm including this for reference of what I've tried and for potential recommendations of a better solution.*

The second issue, which is unresolved, is dynamically prepending our context route  to the redirect urls generated by the web app. For example, the `Home` button in the top navigation bar redirects the user to the root url (`https://aws.our-server-uri.com/` in our example case). I need the flask app to be aware of my context route and append `/knowledge-repo/` to the page root for all links generated.

**What I've tried:**

I want to avoid forking and modifying this repo, so I've focussed on ways that do not involve editing the Flask app html, such as setting a `<base>` tag.

- I've set the `SCRIPT_NAME` environment variable before deploying, but to no avail.
- I've played around with setting some variables in a `config.py` which I passed using the `--config config.py` flag when running `knowledge_repo deploy`, but can't seem to find anything that does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I made some code changes to make it work:

1. Gave URL prefix to the static content.
2. Adding URL prefix to the blueprints in flask.
3. User URL_for with jinja templating to access the routes across HTML and JavaScript.

[Here](https://github.com/GeorgeSabu/knowledge-repo/commit/63196ad028ef30bdfe8a76e5c5636461297d7750) are the code changes.

Comment: Thanks @sabu, will try this out. 
Just out of interest sake, have you tried using the `prepare_app` method in `.knowledge_repo_config.py`? Seems like our use case is exactly what that method is made for, but I can't seem to get any code I write in that method to be executed.

Comment: @RenierBotha I have not used it. But how are you thinking of using it? I would like to try it out too if it can avoid changing the knowledge repo code.

Comment: I thought about adding a middleware to the Flask App...something like the third answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441/add-a-prefix-to-all-flask-routes

This would mean we do not have to fork the knowledge-repo, which would be a major plus.

Comment: Please add the code changes to the post itself. If GitHub goes down your delete that repo then this answer loses value otherwise.