# Flask: serve assets without leading slash using url_for

Tags: python, flask, routes, relative-path

I'm working on a Flask app that uses `url_for` to specify the route to some static assets (js, css, etc). Here's an example from one of the templates:

```
<script src='{{ url_for('static', filename='js/search.js') }}'></script>
```

When this gets rendered into html, the path looks like this:

```
<script src='/static/js/search.js'></script>
```

Is it possible to modify this behavior such that the leading slash is dropped from the rendered script path? The goal is to render the following:

```
<script src='static/js/search.js'></script>
```

I'd be very grateful for any insights others can offer on this question!

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you're not on a root-level page? `../../../static/js/search.js`? Why do you want to avoid the absolute URL in the first place?

Comment: @blender Ah yes. Well I need to serve this beast using a reverse proxy on Apache, such that users who request IP/cats/meow/ get the Flask index route content. But right now the static asset requests fail. I tried setting `app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = IP/cats/meow/` but that does not appear to solve the problem. I'd be grateful for any thoughts you might have on the subject!

Comment: app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] seems promising--investigating now...

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37308920/464744, specifically the last code example

Comment: @Blender Thanks! Was just reading my way down that thread...

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with loading a css file that was on a custom static path.
One fix could be to change the ROOT_DIRECTORY of the application, but this didn't work for my application as I only need to change the static path.

I used a combination of static_folder and static_url_path:

```
STATIC_URL_PATH = '/your/custom/path/static' # Where the css is stored
STATIC_FOLDER = 'your/custom/path/static'

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=STATIC_FOLDER,
            static_url_path=STATIC_URL_PATH)
```

As you can see, the main difference is the leading / in the beginning, but this made the app to be able to find the css.