# flask-admin under URI breaks links to views

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

While developing the app flask-admin properly loaded the multiple stylesheets and javascript files. But once deployed the path to those files is incorrect, as well as the links to the views.

I am deploying the app at `http://mydomian.com/services/`. It seems that the paths are missing the "services" part.

I am configuring the *flask-admin* as:

```py
admin = Admin(app, index_view=MyHomeView(), name='DB Admin', template_mode=None, static_url_path = '', endpoint='admin', url='/treatabolome_service/')
```

So the issues are:

1. The stylesheets and javascript files appear as `/admin/vendor/jquery.min.js?v=3.3.1` instead of `/services/admin/vendor/jquery.min.js?v=3.3.1`
2. The links to the views appearsas `http://mydomian.com/services//PBTable/` instead of `http://mydomian.com/services/admin/PBTable/`

How I have to fill the `static_url_path`, `endpoint`, and `url` to solve this issue?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for APPLICATION_ROOT configuration entry. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18967744/6682517) explains how to use it.