# How to set an api prefix in a flask application?

Tags: python, api, flask, configuration, namespaces

I'm using this way to set it

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = "/api"

@app.route("/posts")
def posts():
    ...
    return response, 200
```

I want to get the endpoint as:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/posts
```

But can't show correctly. Got 404 Not Found error.

If use `@app.route("/api/posts")`, it works.

`APPLICATION_ROOT` is a builtin [feature](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#APPLICATION_ROOT), why it doesn't work?

Comment: That's not what APPLICATION_ROOT does. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967441/add-a-prefix-to-all-flask-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `SCRIPT_NAME` env var with your prefix.

Please note, this is a WSGI server feature, and thus the Flask development server ignores it.

Read more at https://dlukes.github.io/flask-wsgi-url-prefix.html