# How to host a Flask app on a subfolder / URL prefix with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a flask app which I want to host it on a subfolder of a website, like `example.com/cn`.

I configured my nginx like

```
location /cn {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
}
```

So if I access `example.com/cn`, It will redirect to the index page of flask.

However, I have wrote the routes of other pages on flask like `app.route('/a')`. So if I click the link of page `a`, the URI is `example.com/a`, then `nginx` cannot redirect it to the right ​page.

​I think I can rewrite all the routes on flask like `app.route('/cn/a')`, but it's complex. And if someday I want to deploy it on `example.com/en`, I think I need to rewrite all the routes again.

Does anyone have other methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add **APPLICATION_ROOT** params to your flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/cn'
```

if you need to host more than one application on your server, you can configure nginx to redirect all request to your specific flask app served by gunicorn like this. (it is not necessary if your server hosts only one application) Find out more about gunicorn and nginx here: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name example.com;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path_to_example_flask_app_1/app.sock;
    }

    location /cn/{
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path_to_example_flask_app_cn/app.sock;
    }
}
```

serve flask app with gunicorn:
A complete exmaple here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

```
#move into project directory
/path_to_gunicorn/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:app.sock -m 007 run:app
```

If you are using **flask_restful** instead, you can specify the root path also in the following way:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = False
api = Api(app, prefix='/cn')

api.add_resource(ResourceClass, '/example_path') #will be served when the resource is requested at path /cn/example_path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: It looks like it's a solution. But when I try to set `app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/cn'`, it has no use. I think the problem is from flask itself.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to host your application under `/api` with Nginx.

First, config your URL prefix to `location` and `X-Forwarded-Prefix` header:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /api;
    }
}
```

Then use Werkzeug's `ProxyFix` middleware to tell Flask it's behind a proxy:

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(
    app.wsgi_app, x_for=1, x_proto=1, x_host=1, x_prefix=1
)
```

See also:

- [Deploying with Nginx](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/deploying/nginx/)
- [Tell Flask it is Behind a Proxy](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/deploying/proxy_fix/)

P.S. If you are using OpenAPI, also remember to update the `servers` field to indicate the location of the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `url_prefix="/cn"` option when defining blueprints:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/blueprints/#nesting-blueprints