# ProxyFix does not seem to be working (Flask behind nginx)

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have a server running nginx. I'm trying to set up a Flask application at a specific sub-URL (e.g. `http://server/app/` maps to Flask application's `/`). If it matters, ultimately I intend for multiple Flask applications to run at various other sub-URLs on this same server.

I'm new to all of this so I've been running through tutorials, in particular I've followed these guides / posts:

- [Flask + Gunicorn + Nginx Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-22-04)
- [Flask docs re: nginx](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/deploying/nginx/)
- [Flask docs re: ProxyFix](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/deploying/proxy_fix/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75123044

I have a section in my nginx *sites-available/default* file like this:

```
        location /firmware {
                 proxy_pass http://localhost:6001;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /firmware;
        }
```

It seems to be working fine (the Flask app is on 6001):

- I've confirmed that requests to `/firmware` are forwarded to the Flask app.
- I've confirmed that the HTTP headers are present in the request and that they all contain the expected values:

  ```
  X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.98.113
  X-Forwarded-Proto: http
  X-Forwarded-Host: 192.168.99.223
  X-Forwarded-Prefix: /firmware
  ```

Also, I'm using `ProxyFix` in the Flask app to let the app know it's behind a proxy. I've got this bit of code when creating the application:

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix

app = Flask(__name__)

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(
    app.wsgi_app,
    x_for=1,
    x_proto=1,
    x_host=1,
    x_prefix=1
)

@app.route("/")
def ... ():
    ...
```

However, the Flask application still sees the request as `/firmware/`, rather than `/`. I've verified this by checking the output logs when running the app via `flask`, and also by adding a route for `/firmware/` to test if it gets hit (it does). The `/` route does not get a hit.

The behavior is the same whether I run the application via `flask` or `gunicorn`, that doesn't seem to matter.

What step have I missed / what am I doing wrong here? Why is the Flask application still getting requests for `/firmware/` even though I've set up `ProxyFix` and the HTTP headers?

Comment: In nginx add a trailing slash to your proxy `proxy_pass http://localhost:6001/;` and see if it works.

Comment: @0x00 Hey... that totally worked! Thank you so much, I was really banging my head on the wall here. I don't really understand *why* it worked but if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: Added it as an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nginx add a trailing slash to your proxy `proxy_pass http://localhost:6001/;`

From the [nginx documentation about proxy_pass](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:
>
> ```
> location /name/ {
>     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
> }
> ```
>
> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI:
>
> ```
> location /some/path/ {
>    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
> }
> ```

So in your case without the trailing slash, nginx was passing the request to flask (gunicorn) as `http://localhost:6001/firmware` instead of `http://localhost:6001/`